# gproc and adding / removing nodes dynamically

Tags: erlang

In the application I try to develop, nodes on different hosts should be able to join and leave  the network as needed and find services and use pub/sub. Gproc seems a perfect fit, however, it doesn't seem to support adding and removing nodes dynamically in the global mode. This issue has been discussed before [here](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2011-August/060412.html).  With the gproc_dist all option, only the currently known hosts will be allowed access but not any new hosts.

Is there a (new) way to get this working or is gproc not able to do what I want?

Thanks

Comment: I have been facing the same issue a while back. I found out that each purpose has it's own best implementations... I need to know what kind of work your server is doing (no need to be really specific) to get you on the right direction.

Comment: The system should have many similarities with the Robot Operating System ([ROS.org](http://ros.org)). It should have a way to locate resources on the LAN which are either services or publishers. After locating a resource, the clents / subscribers use P2P communication. There is also a parameter server which holds parameters and should notify subscribers when a parameter value changes.

Comment: So how's your implementation, the pub/sub is for tcp connected client to your server, and need to access to them from any node they are connected to, is that right ?

Comment: I am not planning to use TCP but keep with Erlang messaging. So I need name lookup, parameter storage and pub/sub. All this perfectly fits into gproc, except for the issue of adding and removing nodes globally to gproc. The project’s main goal is learning Erlang and distributed computing and some fault tolerance. I am not trying to reimplement an existing system.

Comment: What is the number of elements you are expecting in the pub/sub ?

Comment: @Lemoi have you learned how to do this? I'm approaching Erlang and am curious about how to create a dynamically network of communicating nodes.

Comment: @Juliano Nothing new on my part. The best place to go with your question is erlang-questions@erlang.org. The gproc developer is on that list.